# How to create a DataProvider using specific elements from an XML object in Flash AS3

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, dataprovider

I have this XML (Flash/AS3):

```
 <channel>
 <title>...</title>
 <description>...</description>
 <item><summary>...</summary><detail>...</detail></item>
 <item><summary>...</summary><detail>...</detail></item>
 ...
 </channel>
```

I want to create a DataProvider containing the  elements (for use in a datagrid).

I thought this would work:

```
var items:XML = new XML(evt.target.data); //url loader event listener 'complete'
trace(items..item is XMLList); // true
myDP = new DataProvider(items..item);
```

But I get this error:

```
 TypeError: Error: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert 
   <item><summary>...</summary><detail>...</detail></item>
   <item><summary>...</summary><detail>...</detail></item>
     ...
 to Array or DataProvider.
    at fl.data::DataProvider/getDataFromObject()
    at fl.data::DataProvider()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give the DataProvider an XML, not an XMLList:

```
var items:XML = <channel>
   <title>Title</title>
   <description>Description</description>
   <item><summary>Summary 1</summary><detail>Detail 1</detail></item>
   <item><summary>Summary 2</summary><detail>Detail 2</detail></item>
</channel>;

var xml:XML = <dummy/>;
xml.appendChild(items..item);
list.dataProvider = new DataProvider(xml);
list.labelFunction = function(item:Object) {
   return item.summary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create an instance of DataProvider. You should be able to directly assign the dataProvider property with the XML instance. The dataProvider setter will automatically determine the object type and handle it appropriately.

Comment: So I tried this: myData.dataProvider = items..item;   (myData is a datagrid)  and I receive:  TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert XMLList@af7f2b1 to fl.data.DataProvider.

Comment: Please read: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#dataProvider are you using mx.controls.DataGrid?